# General way to pass data to UIViewControllers when using a UITabController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I still haven't grasped this transfer with the structure below. I have read many posts, and have seen the same unanswered post by others, but no resolution.

I will try to simplify the question to make it easier for all.

The structure of the project is:
UITabbar with tab1 and tab2

Tab1 has a Nav controller-->ViewController1

Tab2 has a Nav controller -->ViewController2

In viewcontroller1 (tab1) I have object X.

In ViewCOntroller2 (tab2) I want to display object X.

Don't worry about displaying, that's the easy part.

[image]

Question: How do you pass object X from tab1 to tab2. (what is the general pattern).

If you want to do it using prepareForSegue, is this ok, or is there a better way.

If using prepareForSegue, where do you drag the segue to?

1. The tabbarcontroller

   [image]

OR*****
2. to the second VC
[image]

Hopefully this is clear enough. With this in mind how would you perform the transfer?

Using the segue 1:
[image]

I tried doing this:

```
//(From View controller 1)

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CreateObjectXToDisplayObjectX"])

            ViewController2* vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
            UITabBarController* tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
            vc2 = (ViewController2 *)[[tbc customizableViewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    //Crash here with with [MainNavigationControllerDesign setViewController1Delegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1064ef70'
            vc2.viewController1Delegate=self;
            vc2.objectXAtViewController2 = _objectXFromViewController1;
        }
    }
```

So, how is this Object X transfer accomplished?
Thank you in advance

Comment: So I am using a delegate... (hence line vc2.viewController1Delegate=self;) this is @protocol and I have transfered the object like this before but only using the segue (2) method. However it doesnt switch tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use segues in this way. Segues always instantiate new controllers when you go to them, but you already have these controllers embedded in the tab bar controller. If you were setting this up in code, I would say use a delegate, but if you set this up in IB, it's hard to do that. From VC2, you can get a reference to VC1's navigation controller with self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0]. VC1 will be that navigation controller's topViewController, so, putting that together, and adding a cast, you can access VC1 like this:

```
ViewController1 *vc1 = (ViewController1 *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers[0] topViewController];
```

Once you have that reference, you can access any of vc1's properties. Don't forget to import ViewController1.h into ViewController2's .m file.

Comment: could you explain please. What delegate are you talking about? I already have @protocol VIewController1Delegate<NSObject>

Comment: @Will, to use a delegate you have to have a reference to the controller that you're going to be the delegate of so you can write something like vc2.delegate = self, but as I said, it's hard to get that reference other than by doing what I did in my answer. So, if you already have that reference, you can use it directly rather than using a delegate. I think in this case, using a delegate is just adding unnecessary complication.

Comment: so no segue necessary? and the reference substitutes @protocol delegate?. And by reference you mean the line you posted?  So how do you load the next tab?

Comment: OK, so If i understand you correctly, link segue (style 2 that I show in the images here), then in prepare for segue, do nothing (going from VC1 to VC2), then in VC1, type in your line of code, then acces the object like   (in VC2)|| _objectX=vc1.objectx;||||||||  Is this correct?

Comment: ok, perfect, I will add a very detailed step by step of what happened so that people can use it in the future.

Comment: @Will, There should be NO segues! You don't segue between controllers embedded in a tabBar controller, so get rid of prepare for segue. The code I have above would go in vc2 not vc1. If you need to go to another tab in code, then use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; or whatever tab you want to go to.

Comment: one more thing to clarify, what if I have three tabs and tabs 1 and tabs 2 send info to tab 3. How can I pick which callback to use (using your line of code)

Comment: @Will, not sure what you mean by callback. If tab 3 needs info from both tabs 1 and 2, then you need to get a reference to both of those tabs in tab 3.

Comment: if user wants objectx he goes to tab1, result displayed in tab3. If user wants objectY he goes to tab2, result displayed in tab3. If I put your line twice (one for each controller), won't it crash when both lines are ran?

Comment: @Will, no, it's just asking the tab bar controller for some information about its controllers, and assigning that to a variable. You can do that as many times as you want.