# UIStoryBoard load rootController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I have UIStoryBoard approach in my App and it has screens in the following pattern:

**UINavigationController**  ->  MyMainController  ->  UITabBarController->  UINavigationController ->  MyHomeController

And From MyHomeController there is a UIButton and action of which is

UINavigationController  ->  MyDetailsController

Now, from MyDetailsController I want to comeback to MyMainController. The problem I am facing I don't have UINavigationController Highlighted in black to be accessed from MyDetailsController.

Also, UIStoryBoard does not have to get UIViewController based on a Identifier.

It has but instantiates a UIViewController which would be not a better solution.

```
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

Comment: Why not make the tab bar controller the root controller?

Comment: @rdelmar I don't want UITabBar at the bottom for MyMainController.

Comment: Then you can hide the tab bar when that controller is on screen. The structure would be more simple and straightforward with the tab bar at the base. But the overall design really depends on what you're doing in all these different controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar I don't want to show MyMainController with UITabBar item. with the approach you mentioned I have to add and remove if from UITabBarItems though I will be hiding UITabBar. So managing it becomes a bit overwork.

Comment: You could probably use an unwind segue to get back to your MyMainController.

Comment: Thats a nice Idea. But when i perform Unwind, will it release all the ViewControllers between them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23399/discussion-between-andypaul-and-rdelmar)

Answer (score 0):

Uitabbarcontroller first. Then add uinavigation controller, then add a viewcontroller of your choice as the root controller of the nav controller

This post has good images that show this issue

[General way to pass data to UIViewControllers when using a UITabController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383156/general-way-to-pass-data-to-uiviewcontrollers-when-using-a-uitabcontroller/14383826#comment20013888_14383826)